# how to get the pid of a process which has sent a SIGABRT signal to another process which has exited dumping core

Tags: coredump

how to get the pid of a process which has sent a SIGABRT signal to another process which has exited dumping core

Answer (score 1):

In short, by installing a signal handler for SIGABRT. More specifically, if you specify the `SA_SIGINFO` flag when installing the signal handler, then the `siginfo_t` structure should be populated with extra info about the signal, including the sender's PID etc.